# How to get pallet index (u8) of a pallet in runtime?

Tags: polkadot

how to get pallet index (u8) of a pallet in runtime?

I have a scenario, where I have to add filter like this https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/Acala/blob/master/runtime/acala/src/lib.rs#L187

but method would accept `u8` pallet index instead of `Call`

Comment: It might be possible, but why use pallet index and not a concrete `Call`? This is far more intuitive and less likely to break. It also is ***extremely*** important to understand filter configurations in XCM for your chain and others interfacing with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
use frame_support::traits::PalletInfoAccess;

let my_pallet_index = MyPallet::index();
```

This will give you the index of your pallet.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this out by adding a simple test into your runtime:

```
#[test]
fn get_pallet_by_index() {
    use frame_support::traits::PalletInfoAccess;
    let balance_index = Balances::index();
    println!("index is {:?}", balance_index);
    // trigger an error to easily see the print statement
    assert!(false);
}
```

The message that appears is:

```
---- get_pallet_by_index stdout ----
index is 5
```

And this matches what you can see in in the `construct_runtime!` where I ran this test:

```
// Create the runtime by composing the FRAME pallets that were previously configured.
construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Runtime where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic
    {
        System: frame_system,
        RandomnessCollectiveFlip: pallet_randomness_collective_flip,
        Timestamp: pallet_timestamp,
        Aura: pallet_aura,
        Grandpa: pallet_grandpa,
        Balances: pallet_balances,
        TransactionPayment: pallet_transaction_payment,
        Sudo: pallet_sudo,
        // Include the custom logic from the pallet-template in the runtime.
        TemplateModule: pallet_template,
    }
);
```

See that Balances is the 5th index (6th item) in the list.